# HOW TO GET ALL THE AUDIO FILES USING MEDIASTORE

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, cursor, mediastore

I am trying to get all the audio files from the mobile device but I am able to get one SD_card files or Internal storage file at a time but how I can get both internal and external file information using mediastore and what changes will I do .by changing EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI  i am able to get the internal files but how I can get both at the same time. I my audio retriver method

```
 private void parseAllAudio(String type) {
    try {
        String TAG = "Audio";
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (cur == null) {
            // Query failed...
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve music: cursor is null :-(");

        }
        else if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
            // Nothing to query. There is no music on the device. How boring.
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to move cursor to first row (no query results).");

        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Listing...");
            // retrieve the indices of the columns where the ID, title, etc. of the song are

            // add each song to mItems
            do {
                int artistColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int albumColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                int durationColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
                int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int filePathIndex = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                Log.i(TAG, "Title column index: " + String.valueOf(titleColumn));
                Log.i(TAG, "ID column index: " + String.valueOf(titleColumn));

                Log.i("Final ", "ID: " + cur.getString(idColumn) + " Title: " + cur.getString(titleColumn) + "Path: " + cur.getString(filePathIndex));
                MediaFileInfo audio = new MediaFileInfo();
                audio.setFileName(cur.getString(titleColumn));
                audio.setFilePath(cur.getString(filePathIndex));
                audio.setFileType(type);
                mediaList.add(audio);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess thats not possible , first you fetch internal audio files and then external  audio file using two methods , or another solution fetch all audio file string paths and then using MediaMetadataRetriever you can retrieve all  information . here is MediaMetadataRetriever  example http://mrbool.com/how-to-extract-meta-data-from-media-file-in-android/28130

Comment: its possible using mediastore thats why I am trying

Comment: How about run it twice? Make the method take the Uri as a parameter and pass it to the Cursor, then call `parseAllAudio` with the appropriate Uris. `mediaList` seems global so it should work without much changes.